# Support landscape and portrait device orientation for specific view controller in ios, swift 3

Tags: swift3, iso

I am working on an iOS application, in which all ViewControllers support only Portrait orientation, except one ViewController, which supports both Portrait and landscape. I try this code for that ViewController

```
 override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .landscapeLeft
}

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .landscapeLeft
}
```

but this didn't work, Can any one help ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in AppDelegate add this event

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {


    if let navigationController = UIApplication.topViewController() {

        if navigationController is YOURVIEWCONTROLLERNAME  {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
        }

        else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
        }
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}

extension UIApplication {
class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(base: presented)
    }
    return base
}
```

change YOURVIEWCONTROLLERNAME to your view controller